# rails check_box_tag default unchecked value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

Is there any way to set check_box_tag unchecked value to any other value than nil? Something like:

```
check_box_tag :active, ['true', 'false'], ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML specifications unchecked checkboxes are not included when sending the form. So there is no "unchecked value" for a checkbox.

There is a workaround though - you include a hidden input with the same name attribute as the checkbox:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="active" value="deader then dead">
<input type="checkbox" name="active">
```

Since key/value pairs have to be sent in the same order they appear in the form the checkbox will override the hidden input if it is checked.

The higher level Rails [checkbox helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) has this workaround built in.